# Regular expression(max 3 letters and one or more dots in every possible order)

Tags: regex

I am trying to make a regular expression for a pattern that will contain 4 characters in which there will be one or more dots (".") without order
(*Example : asd. , .afd , .AF.* )

So far i got this **[a-zA-Z(.+)]{4}** but it doesn't seem to work ( it matches both alex and ale. ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[a-zA-Z(.+)]{4}` pattern matches 4 characters: either a letter, or `(`, `.`, `+` or `)` literal symbols.

You may use

```
^(?=.*[.])[a-zA-Z.]{4}$
```

**Details**:

- `^` - start of the string
- `(?=.*[.])`  - a positive lookahead requiring that there should be at least 1 dot after any 0+ chars
- `[a-zA-Z.]{4}`  - 4 occurrences of a letter or dot
- `$` - end of string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HY5owh/1).

Answer (score 1):

If your regex language supports lookahead assertions,

```
(?=.{0,3}\.)[A-Za-z.]{4}
```

This asserts that there is a `.` after 0-3 characters, and also the 4 characters are all A-Z or `.`.

If your regex language does not support lookahead assertions, then you'll have to do this in a somewhat more painful way,

```
\.[A-Za-z.]{3}|[A-Za-z]\.[A-Za-z.]{2}|[A-Za-z]{2}\.[A-Za-z.]|[A-Za-z]{3}\.
```

with a case for `.` in each position.